Rearrange array with a predefined order of matching numbers
I have two 2D arrays
array1 = np.array(
        [[1, 2],
         [2, 1],
         [3, 3]])

array2 = np.array(
        [[2, 3],
         [3, 2],
         [1, 1]])

I want to sort array2 in a way so that the values and order in the second column of array1 matches with first column of array2
desired output would be a numpy array that looks like this
sorted_array2 =
    [[2, 3]
     [1, 1]
     [3, 2]]

then combine the two arrays to get a final array like this
[[1, 2, 3],
 [2, 1, 1],
 [3, 3, 2]]

Thank you for your time.

Actually, no. Because I don't want to make any change to array1. I have a series of array in 3D and I want to do this process in a cascading order. Which is why I cannot make any changes to prior array when sorting the second one.

This would be a simple merge in pandas. Would that work or do you want a solution without more external packages?

any package would be fine.

Convert to pandas dataframes and perform a merge. If you want the sorted array2, just slice the merged array.
df1 = pd.DataFrame(array1, columns = [0, 1])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(array2, columns = [1, 2])

merged = df1.merge(df2, on = 1).values
sorted_df2 = merged[:, 1:]

